# adhoc wireless java game development

Tags: java, wireless, adhoc

I want to develop a Java game that works on adhoc wireless environment.  Do you know any source that I can search for it and learn for it?

Comment: This is a very vague and broad question. Could you be more specific about what work you've done so far and where you're stuck?

Comment: I solve all my problem  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adhoc and wireless is not related to Java.  An ad-hoc wireless network is something that two computers can set up between each other to create a network.  At that point your Java game is using a network the same as any other network (the fact that is is wireless and ad-hoc is irrelevant - to Java it looks exactly the same as a wired network for example).

Your java program will then have the same TCP/IP and UDP/IP stack available to it and can use Socket/ServerSocket (TCP) or DatagramSocket (UDP) to communicate.

The following page gives an overview of networking in Java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html

And the following page has an example of a very small simple networked java game that might be helpful to get to grips with the basics:

http://www.dr-mikes-maths.com/tictactoe.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a online game you must learn the following classes:

1. Java.net.ServerSocket
   This class will let you host a socket at a specified ip and port.
2. Java.net.Socket
   This class will let you to connet to a socket at a specified ip and port.
3. java.io.InputStream
   This class will let you send streams from a socket to another.
4. java.io.OutputStream
   This class will let you get streams from a socket to another.
5. java.lang.Thread
   This class is very important but i cannot describe it.
   an alternative to this class is the Runnable interface.

These are enough.